# Fragment based ViewPager as RecyclerView item produces Null Object Reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have assigned Fragment based ViewPager as RecyclerView item. The **`onBindViewHolder()`** inside `RecyclerView.Adapter`

produces

**`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`**

while setting text using `setText()`. Means the view is not created at the time of binding the value.

I am not able to figure it out that -> why the view is not created, even though `ViewPager` and `Fragment` inflation is handled in `onCreateViewHolder()`? I tried inflation also in `onBindViewHolder()` but still the same.

How can i force `Page Fragment` inflation before `onBindViewHolder()`.

**RecyclerView.Adapter**

```
public class MainListRVA extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> implements ConstantValues {

    FragmentManager oFm;

    private int viewPagerId = 1;

    private static ArrayList<MainListItem> oListItems = new ArrayList<MainListItem>();

    MainListRVA(ArrayList<MainListItem> theArray, FragmentManager fm){
        oListItems = theArray;
        oFm = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_pager_main_list_item_folder, parent, false);
        return new FolderVH(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        FolderVH folderVH = (FolderVH) holder;
        MainListItem listItem = oListItems.get(position);

        folderVH.fragmentOne.title.setText(listItem.oTitle);
        folderVH.fragmentTwo.title.setText(listItem.oDetail);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////THIS GIVE NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
    }

    public class FolderVH extends ViewHolder {

        FolderMainPageFragment fragmentOne, fragmentTwo;
        ViewPager viewPager;

        FolderVH(View v) {

            super(v);

            ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

            fragmentOne = FolderMainPageFragment.newInstance("one");
            fragmentTwo = FolderMainPageFragment.newInstance("two");

            fragments.add(fragmentOne);
            fragments.add(fragmentTwo);

            FolderVPAdapter folderVPAdapter = new FolderVPAdapter(oFm, fragments);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            viewPager.setId(viewPagerId++);
            viewPager.setAdapter(folderVPAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return oListItems.size();
    }

    void move(int fromPos, int toPos){ }

    void remove(int position){ }
}
```

**FragmentPagerAdapter**

```
public class FolderVPAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public FolderVPAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

**Pager Fragment**

```
public class FolderMainPageFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView title;

    public static FolderMainPageFragment newInstance(String text) {
        return new FolderMainPageFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list_item_view, container, false);
        this.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final solution that i have.

1) I added a condition to check if view is null while binding in `onBindViewHolder`

2) If null i just flagged boolean `bindExceptionally` as true inside the fragment class.

3) When fragment will create view at `onCreateView()` it will check if the flag is true to set the text. Else it will simply move ahead without setting text.

Note: fragments are inflated in `onCreateViewHolder()` and not in `onBindViewHolder()` hence fragments inflated only once and then they are recycled.

**Updated - RecyclerView.Adapter**

```
public class MainListRVA extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> implements ConstantValues {

    FragmentManager oFm;

    private int viewPagerId = 1;

    static ArrayList<MainListItem> oListItems = new ArrayList<MainListItem>();

    MainListRVA(ArrayList<MainListItem> theArray, FragmentManager fm){
        oListItems = theArray;
        oFm = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_pager_main_list_item_folder, parent, false);
        return new FolderVH(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Log.e("onBindViewHolder", "onBindViewHolder");

        FolderVH folderVH = (FolderVH) holder;
        MainListItem listItem = oListItems.get(position);
        folderVH.viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        if(folderVH.fragmentOne.title != null) {
            folderVH.fragmentOne.title.setText(listItem.oTitle);
        } else {
            folderVH.fragmentOne.bindExceptionally = true;
            folderVH.fragmentOne.currListItem = listItem;
        }
    }

    public class FolderVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        FolderMainPageFragment fragmentOne, fragmentTwo;
        ViewPager viewPager;

        FolderVH(View v) {

            super(v);

            Log.e("FolderVH", "FolderVH");

            ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

            fragmentOne = FolderMainPageFragment.newInstance("one");
            fragmentTwo = FolderMainPageFragment.newInstance("two");

            fragments.add(fragmentOne);
            fragments.add(fragmentTwo);

            FolderVPAdapter folderVPAdapter = new FolderVPAdapter(oFm, fragments);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            viewPager.setId(viewPagerId++);
            viewPager.setAdapter(folderVPAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return oListItems.size();
    }

    void move(int fromPos, int toPos){ }

    void remove(int position){ }
}
```

**Updated - Pager Fragment**

```
public static class FolderMainPageFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView title;
    boolean bindExceptionally = false;
    MainListItem currListItem;

    public static FolderMainPageFragment newInstance(String text) {
        return new FolderMainPageFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list_item_view_folder, container, false);
        this.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_title);

        if(bindExceptionally) {
            title.setText(currListItem.oTitle);
            bindExceptionally = false;
            currListItem = null;
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course `title` is null.

`FolderMainPageFragment` hasn't even started its life cycle by the time you are accessing `title`. Which means `onCreateView` is not called yet and layout has not been inflated so has `title`.

As far as inflation in `onCreateViewHolder()` is concerned, you are merely inflating the layout `view_pager_main_list_item_folder` and not `main_list_item_view` (from `FolderMainPageFragment` which contains `title`) because the `FolderVPAdapter` hasn't even started yet.

Also why would you want to put a `ViewPager` inside a `RecyclerView` is beyond me? Perhaps you could do something else.

To pass data to `Fragment` write a method **handleArgs()** in `FolderMainPageFragment`.

```
public class FolderMainPageFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView title;
    Bundle mBundle;

    public void handleArgs(Bundle bundle) {
        mBundle = bundle;

        if (title != null)
            title.setText(bundle.getString("title"));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list_item_view, container, false);
        this.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_title);

        if (mBundle != null)        //    When handleArgs() is called before onCreateView().
            handleArgs(mBundle);
        return v;
    }
}
```

The advantage of writing your own `Bundle` method is that you can now use it in **onBindViewHolder()**. However you need to come up with a way where Bundle's new instance is not created in **onBindViewHolder()**.

Comment: I was bit aware about it, but was not sure. But still is there any way to force Page Fragment inflation before onBindViewHolder(). or any other way to set the text after the inflation?

Comment: Sure, you can pass the title along with any other info that you want via a `Bundle` and retrieve it in `FolderMainPageFragment.onCreate()`  by calling `getArguments()`.

Comment: You are correct. @Furedal also suggested it. **But** it will hinder the benefit of RecyclerView. As with this approach I will have to **Inflate** the ViewPager Fragments and Pass value from `onBindViewHolder()`. I don't want to inflate it there.

Comment: I posted in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45842739/3474961) the similar approach but without bundle. There i check for null condition in the `onBindViewHolder()` and flag the boolean `bindExceptionally` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As Abbas mentioned, the views inside the fragments is not initiated at the time when `onBindViewHolder` are called.

You should read a bit about fragments, if fragment is the way you want to go, then you should separate the view logic for the particular fragment inside the fragment.
The only information you are supposed to pass to the fragments is the ones you put in the bundle you pass with `setArguments` at initiation of the fragment. There is a lot of lifecycle issues which will give you a pain otherwise.

In this case, if you want to set title to the fragments, you should instead do something like this at initiation:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("title", "My title");
fragmentOne = FolderMainPageFragment.newInstance("one");
fragmentOne.setArguments(args);
```

And then in your fragments `onViewCreated()`

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
title.setText(args.getString("title"));
```

Comment: For this approach I will have to pass value in `onCreateViewHolder()` to the `ViewHolder` or in `onBindViewHolder()` by calling a custom method in view holder to create and assign fragments to `ViewPager`. This will fade the benifit of using `RecyclerView`. Beacuse on every call to `onBindViewHolder()` fragments of ViewPager will require to be inflated and assigned via adapter

Comment: I require complete viewgroup of the recyclerview item to be inflated inside `onCreateViewHolder()` so that i can reuse the same.

Comment: Why do you need to use Fragments? Maybe you just want to use a regular PagerAdapter which inflates views directly. Will certainly give you less problem :)

Comment: I will surely try that out.

Comment: @Fuderal **I tried using PagerAdapter**. It also has the same problem of inflating the View of a Page after `onBindViewHolder()` is called. **ON THAT** it is bit complex to handle and set views from separate PAGES while using simple PagerAdapter ***because*** we are inflating all the views directly under `PagerAdapter`